GCP - Cloud tasks - Grpc.Core.RpcException
Intermittently, when creating a cloud task on gcp I get this exception.
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake. ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Security.SslStream'.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.")
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake.
 ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Security.SslStream'.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ThrowIfExceptional>g__ThrowExceptional|126_0(ExceptionDispatchInfo e)
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SetupAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SetupAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConstructHttp2ConnectionAsync(Stream stream, HttpRequestMessage request, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConstructHttp2ConnectionAsync(Stream stream, HttpRequestMessage request, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.BalancerHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<<WithRetry>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

In this method
  public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Publish(CloudTaskIntegrationEvent taskIntegrationEvent)
  {
    var parent = new QueueName(_projectId, _location, taskIntegrationEvent.Queue);
    var baseUrl = taskIntegrationEvent.BaseUrl ?? _baseUrl;

    var fullEndpointUrl = $"{baseUrl}/{taskIntegrationEvent.Endpoint}";

    _logger.LogInformation("Full Endpoint Url for Cloud Task: {FullEndPointUrl}", fullEndpointUrl);

    var httpRequest = new HttpRequest
    {
      HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
      Url = fullEndpointUrl,
      Body = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8(taskIntegrationEvent.Payload),
      Headers =
        {
          {"Content-Type", "application/json"}
        }
    };

    if(_gcpServiceAccountId != null)
    {
      var oidcToken = new OidcToken
      {
        ServiceAccountEmail = _gcpServiceAccountId
      };
      httpRequest.OidcToken = oidcToken;
    }

    var task = new Google.Cloud.Tasks.V2.Task
    {
      HttpRequest = httpRequest
    };

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(taskIntegrationEvent.TaskName))
      task.Name = $"{parent}/tasks/{taskIntegrationEvent.TaskName}";

    try
    {
      _logger.LogInformation("Creating cloud task in {Queue} with payload {Payload}", taskIntegrationEvent.Queue, taskIntegrationEvent.Payload);

      var request = new CreateTaskRequest
      {
        Parent = parent.ToString(),
        Task = task
      };

      request.Task.ScheduleTime = Timestamp.FromDateTime(
        DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(taskIntegrationEvent.Delay + _defaultDelay));
      var response = await _cloudTasksClient.CreateTaskAsync(request);
      _logger.LogInformation("Task {Name} created", response.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      _logger.LogError(e, "Error while creating could task for task |  {Queue}, {EventType}, {Payload}", taskIntegrationEvent.Queue, taskIntegrationEvent.EventType, taskIntegrationEvent.Payload);
    }
  }

I am using GCP's nuget package to send the request - package "Google.Cloud.Tasks.V2" -v 3.5.0
I am currently using .Net8.
I am sending hundreds of thousands of requests and this will happen about 100 times a day.
I have not had any luck debugging this.
Only thing I can think of doing is adding a re-try to the call. However I am wondering if there is a way to prevent the problem altogether.

"Only thing I can think of doing is adding a re-try to the call." I'd be slightly surprised if that helped, given that it looks like it's failing to establish the network connection - but then, given that you've got lots of requests that are working, maybe I'm misdiagnosing that part. I would suggest trying to add an explicit reference to Google.Api.Gax.Grpc version 4.9.0, which will then depend on a newer version of Grpc.Net.Client... that's definitely helped for some issues with HTTP/3.0, so it might help here. That's not an error I've seen before though.

(Obviously when we next release the Tasks package, it'll pick up the new GAX version anyway - it's just that the API hasn't changed for 6 months, so we haven't re-released just for the dependency update...)

Thank you @JonSkeet. Going to see if that will help.
I also I am going have our dev ops look and see if it is a network issue.
